# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '17-18' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm migrating magento 1.9.2.1 to magento 2.0.2..
I can't really understand what is CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID?

Comment: did you found the answer